# Geopandas performance loss when updating from version 0.8.2 to 0.9

Tags: python, performance, geopandas

The OS I'm working on is Microsoft Windows 10 LTSC. I often need to split GeoDataFrames with a minimum number of 350.000 Points into approximately 100 Polygons with:

```
cell_points = gpd.overlay(gdf_points, gdf_polygons, how='intersection')
```

I was very happy when I found this bug report on the geopandas GitHub site:
[https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1793]. A bit further down in the thread, I found that geopandas 0.8.2 was released which works with pygeos. After I had updated from 0.8.1 to 0.8.2 my code executed much much faster. But when I recently updated to version 0.9, I quickly noticed that my code executed much much slower. Luckily, switching back to version 0.8.2 brought back the execution improvement.
What I specifically did is to set up a virtual environment and installed first of all geopandas from conda-forge, then I installed pygeos from conda-forge.
This is the code that I used to measure the time:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from time import perf_counter


print(gpd.__version__)


def create_Polygon(row):
   return Polygon([(i[0], i[1]) for i in row.reshape((4, 2))])


# #### Generate random Points inside (0, 10) ######
df_points = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(100000, 2) * 10, columns=['X', 'Y'])
gdf_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_points, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_points['X'], df_points['Y']))

# #### Generate 100 Polygons (Squares with edge length of 1) inside (0, 10) #####
step = 1
arr = np.zeros(shape=(100, 8))
counter = 0
for i in range(10):
   for j in range(10):
       arr[counter] = [i, j, i+step, j, i+step, j+step, i, j+step]
       counter += 1
gdf_polygons = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=list(range(100)),
                               geometry=np.apply_along_axis(create_Polygon, axis=1, arr=arr))

# #### Intersect Polygons with Points #####
time_start = perf_counter()
cell_points = gpd.overlay(gdf_points, gdf_polygons, how='intersection')
print(f'Time: {(perf_counter() - time_start):.2f} seconds')
```

The execution time of version 0.9 was approximately 40 seconds. The execution time of version 0.8.2 was approximately 0.6 seconds! (Both with Python version 3.9.6, executed in PyCharm). My question is: Can someone recreate this? Is there maybe something else that I should have installed, when updating to geopandas version 0.9 to keep the performance improvements from version 0.8.2?

Comment: Hi, can you report this (copy&paste) as geopandas Github issue? We'll be able to help there better.