# Pygeos option for geopandas slows down read_file procces

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a 95000 item shapefile, I import the file with GeoPandas using `read_file`. The item are polygons with fairly simple geometry, with the biggest polygon with 316 points.

**Problem**

While doing some speed tests using the option `options.use_pygeos = True`  actually slows down the read file process.

I am using GeoPandas version 0.10.2 and pygeos version 0.12.0. I have read that someone had the same problem while upgrading Geopandas from 0.8.2 to 0.9 in this post [Geopandas performance loss when updating from version 0.8.2 to 0.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957885/geopandas-performance-loss-when-updating-from-version-0-8-2-to-0-9)

The actual slow down :

```
time with pygeos 10.6 s
time without pygeos 5.3 s
```

**Question**

Has anybody reproduce this behavior?, how can we avoid this?

**Edit**

This is the extract of the code. I am using it inside a pyqt5 GUI.

I ended up using pyogrio and pygeos. This works almost as a GeoDataFrame, So it is very convenient

data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1abzDcvD3cATuKOOUoBA89p5rwvrgpFci/view?usp=sharing

Another results

```
geopandas + pygeos
geopandas:  9.635942159632514
pygeos: geometry to numpy array:  1.8224096298217773

geopandas - pygeos
geopandas:  6.420444488525391
pygeos: geometry to numpy array:  0.251056432723999

pyogrio + pygeos
pyogrio:  1.9999799728393555
pygeos: geometry to numpy array:  0.06801533699035645
```

**Code**

```
import time
import geopandas as gp
gp.options.use_pygeos = True
import pygeos
import pyogrio


shp = r'00_PREDIO_GENERAL.shp'

t0 = time.time()
gdf = gp.read_file(shp)
print('geopandas: ', time.time() - t0)

t0 = time.time()
p_array, idx_coords = pygeos.get_coordinates(pygeos.from_shapely(gdf.geometry), return_index=True)
print('pygeos: geometry to numpy array: ', time.time() - t0)


t0 = time.time()
gdf = pyogrio.read_dataframe(shp)
print('pyogrio: ', time.time() - t0)

t0 = time.time()
gp.options.use_pygeos = False
p_array, idx_coords = pygeos.get_coordinates(gdf.geometry, return_index=True)
print('pygeos: geometry to numpy array: ', time.time() - t0)
```

Comment: Can you share the whole code? I see approximately the same performance on my data.

Comment: Hi, I will edit it in tonight. Greetings, Chelo.

Comment: hi @martinfleis the question is updated. Greetings, Chelo.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code before reading the shapefiles? I have got this same error so far:

```
import shapely
shapely.speedups.disable()
```